# How to set parameters in a GET request in Java

Tags: java, android, get

So I want to send a GET request with parameters. But it only seems to have conventions for the url you send the request to. Unlike the POST request, I see no way to pass parameters in it.

How I send the GET request now, without parameters (might be wrong):

```
String url = "http://api.netatmo.net/api/getuser";

            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            // optional default is GET
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

            //add request header
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            Log.v(TAG, ("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url));
            Log.v(TAG, ("Response Code : " + responseCode));

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            //print result
            Log.v(TAG, (response.toString()));
```

How I send the POST request with parameters:

```
String url = "https://api.netatmo.net/oauth2/token";
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            //add request header
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

            String urlParameters = "grant_type=password&client_id=myid&client_secret=mysecret&username=myusername&password=mypass";

            // Send post request
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            Log.v(TAG, "\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            Log.v(TAG, "Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
            Log.v(TAG, "Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            //print result
            Log.v(TAG, response.toString());

            access_token = response.substring(17, 74);
            refresh_token = response.substring(93,150);
            getRequest = "/api/getuser?access_token=" + access_token + " HTTP/1.1";

            Log.v(TAG, access_token);
            Log.v(TAG, refresh_token);
            Log.v(TAG, getRequest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the url the API provided confused me greatly. I fixed the url and it works now.

Answer (score 11):

As per the HTTP specification `GET` supports only path params or url params and hence you cannot put the params in HTTP request body as you do in `POST` request.

As Sotirios mentioned in the comments, technically you can still push params in the GET body, but if the APIs are respecting the specs, they will not provide you a way to do it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Point accepted, edited the answer, feel free to edit it further. Thanks!

Comment: There has to be a way to - the API I am using, while terribly written - makes clear there is a way to pass parameters with it - otherwise, they wouldn't use the GET method, as passing parameters is what they are trying to do

Comment: @OddCore Surely your API will provide a way to send GET params in the URL but I am not sure whether it provides a way to push them in message body.

Comment: @JunedAhsan http://dev.netatmo.com/doc/restapi/getuser you'd think they would, wouldn't you...

Comment: oh and btw, I think I only need url parameters, however when I tried it I got a Malformedurl exception...

Comment: @OddCore If you follow the correct URL pattern as mentioned on the link you shared then your request should not be refused as malformed. Try printing the complete URL with path params before sending the request and see whether the URL format is as per the API specs.

Comment: @JunedAhsan "java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /api/getuser?access_token=[SOME_ACCESS_TOKEN] HTTP/1.1" Is what I get, even though the spec says the url needs to be like that

Comment: @OddCore And what is the URL you are forming to hit the Http request?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to add the query params to the request java.net.URL?

```
String url = "http://api.netatmo.net/api/getuser?access_token=" + access_token;
URL obj = new URL(url);
```

Comment: See comments on Juned's answer

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering the same problem, trying this:

```
String bla = "http://api.netatmo.net/api/devicelist?access_token=" + AUTH_TOKEN;
URL url = new URL(bla);

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

String line = "";
String message = "";

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    message += line;
}
```

I got an exception that the syntax was not correct. When I changed the syntax (by for example encoding with UTF 8) the API would just return errors (like 404 not found...).

I finally got it working using this:

```
try
{

        System.out.println("Access Token: " + AUTH_TOKEN);

        String url = "http://api.netatmo.net/api/devicelist";
        String query = "access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode(AUTH_TOKEN, CHARSET);

        URLConnection connection = new URL(url + "?" + query).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", CHARSET);

        InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response));

        String line = "";
        String message = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            message += line;
        }

        return message;


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Note: CHARSET = "UTF-8"